# Reading a file with multiple de-limiters

Tags: python

I am trying to read values from a column of the CSV. The column contains a dictionary per cell with multiple de-limiters each. So I have problems using literal_eval().

For instance, this is how a sample cell looks like,

```
{ 'Store product code':270628, 'consumption tax':10% standard tax rate, 'Item Number': '\ n 
 L06935644 \ u3000  \ n', '': '\ n '}
```

Notice the multiple de-limiters in this particular cell value -  **\ u3000** and **\n**
A simple removal by string.replace() doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> Code:

```
import ast

line="""{ 'Store product code':270628, 'consumption tax':'10% standard tax rate', 'Item Number': '\ n 
 L06935644 \ u3000  \ n', '': '\ n '}"""


parsed=ast.literal_eval(" ".join(line.split()))

print(parsed)
```